# Export images by loop function in Google Earth Engine (error: invalid JSON)

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, loop

I want to export data from the FireCCI V51 product in GEE using a loop function for the years 2001 - 2016 for my studyarea. However, when running the code, the error "invalid JSON" appears.

Here is the code I used:

```
// Create a sequence of the years that want to be evaluated
var yearsEval = ee.List.sequence({
  start: 2001,
  end: 2016,
  step: 1
});

// Function to get the median for each year
var yearFIRES = function(year){
   
  // Create start and end dates for each entry of the yearsEval list
  var dateStart = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year),ee.Number(1),ee.Number(1));
  var dateEnd = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1),ee.Number(12),ee.Number(30));
  
  // Filter image collection according to dates, study area and select Burndate
  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1') 
    .filter(ee.Filter.date(dateStart, dateEnd))
    .filterBounds(studyarea)
    .select('BurnDate');

  // Calculate median
  var median = dataset.median();

  // Clip image to study area
  var imageClip = median.clip(studyarea);
  
  // Add the start year property to each image
  imageClip = imageClip.set('startYear',year);
  
  // Return image
  return ee.Image(imageClip);
};

// Map the function to all the entries in the yearEval list
var resul = yearsEval.map(yearFIRES);

// Create an image collection from the list of images generated in the last step
resul = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(resul);

// Use a loop to export each image in the imagecollection
var i = 0;
for(;i<=15;i++){
  
  // Create a year variable by summing the starting year (2001) and i
  var year = 2001 + i;
  
  // Select the image for that year
  var image = resul.filter(ee.Filter.eq('startYear',year));
  
  // Get the first image, to get an ee.Image object
  image = image.first();
  
  // Export image using the year as variable  
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'FireCCIV51_' + year,
    scale: 250,
    region: studyarea,
    maxPixels: 100000000,
});

}
```

Message:

`Error creating or submitting task Invalid JSON:`

Comment: Not sure where the error is, I ran the code without issues using a random geometry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I now found out that the error was due to my own uploaded shapefile which somehow didn't work anymore.